# Comparison(>,<) on alphanumeric string(java uuid) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table say Files which looks like below.

```
+--------+----------------------------------+
| userid | documentid                       |
+--------+----------------------------------+
| 949489 | 0001420ff9bc40298fcdf6a728be6541 |
| 949489 | 0001ed99f8be48748936bb0d1ddb8fa1 |
| 949489 | 0001faeb412d4f3aae340e3a435715cc |
| 949489 | 00022428dce34902b3cbc4ac1b832963 |
| 949489 | 0003488d119d4456a728d0804ea46f90 |
| 949489 | 00046632106d4baa9bb2fbd9fa87a137 |
| 949489 | 0004de1b7efb4845979221dce38c0b61 |
| 949489 | 00058877ed4a43328b8c364cdca187e1 |
| 949489 | 00059e6cab3349d48861df5a0c679d27 |
```

Here the documentid (java uuid) column is the primary key which is indexed by default. I need to perform  '**>**' operation on documentid.

Can anyone explain in detail, how mysql perform alphanumeric string comparison?Also will there be any kind of performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Next question please provide directly the script data like this, it's not hard to do it and it will be simpler for us.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_so`.`Files` (
     `userId` INT NOT NULL ,
     `documentId` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`documentId`)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;



INSERT INTO `Files`(`userId`, `documentId`) VALUES
(949489,'0001420ff9bc40298fcdf6a728be6541'),
(949489,'0001ed99f8be48748936bb0d1ddb8fa1'),
(949489,'0001faeb412d4f3aae340e3a435715cc'),
(949489,'00022428dce34902b3cbc4ac1b832963'),
(949489,'0003488d119d4456a728d0804ea46f90'),
(949489,'00046632106d4baa9bb2fbd9fa87a137'),
(949489,'0004de1b7efb4845979221dce38c0b61'),
(949489,'00058877ed4a43328b8c364cdca187e1'),
(949489,'00059e6cab3349d48861df5a0c679d27')
```

To understand how it works some query to execute :

```
SELECT '0000abcd00' < '0000abce00'   -- will display 1 means it's true
```

Another query to understand :

```
SELECT * FROM `Files` ORDER BY `documentId` DESC
```

OUTPUT :

```
|userId |documentId                      |
|-------|--------------------------------|  
|949489 |00059e6cab3349d48861df5a0c679d27|  
|949489 |00058877ed4a43328b8c364cdca187e1|  
|949489 |0004de1b7efb4845979221dce38c0b61|  
|949489 |00046632106d4baa9bb2fbd9fa87a137|  
|949489 |0003488d119d4456a728d0804ea46f90|  
|949489 |00022428dce34902b3cbc4ac1b832963|  
|949489 |0001faeb412d4f3aae340e3a435715cc|  
|949489 |0001ed99f8be48748936bb0d1ddb8fa1|  
|949489 |0001420ff9bc40298fcdf6a728be6541|
```

Another query to get the Min and the Max DocumentId :

```
SELECT `userId`, MAX(documentId), MIN(documentId) FROM `Files` GROUP BY `userId`
```

OUTPUT:

```
|userId |MAX(documentId)                      |MIN(documentId)                      |
|-------|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
|949489 |00059e6cab3349d48861df5a0c679d27     |0001420ff9bc40298fcdf6a728be6541     |
```

In conclusion, yes you can compare 2 strings, it will only look the alphanumerical order.